# Does HTML5 Works in Old Browsers?

Tags: php, asp.net, html

I want to know that does **HTML 5 validations** works in old browsers if yes then its great and if not then why HTML validations are developed its a high security risk because if a beginner rely on these validations then it may be harmful for his/her. I added more tags because I want to know the reason behind development of **HTML 5 Validations**
Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at this first? http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms

Comment: @JamesWong this link is not working.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know that does HTML 5 validations works in old browsers

No. New features don't work in old browsers.

> if yes then its great and if not then why HTML validations are developed its a high security risk because if a beginner rely on these validations then it may be harmful for his/her.

It is no more of a security risk than client side JavaScript validation.

Any form of client side validation is there as a convenience for the user, not for security.

If you want security then you *must* use server side validation. You can't perform this until the form has been submitted (and then you need to send an error page back to the browser).

> I want to know the reason behind development of HTML 5 Validations

People have used client side validation for years (because making things more convenient for users is a good thing). Having a method to do it baked in to HTML makes it easier to do and gives a consistent UI.

Answer (score 1):

A relative easy way to check HTML5 support in browsers via Jquery as

```
 function supportsFormaction() {
    var input = document.createElement("input"); // create an element in memory
    return "formAction" in input; // check if the browser supports the attribute
}
```

Now the return of this function would be boolean as

- True: Supported
- False Not Supported

---

**Logic**: `FormAction` is a `HTML5` property and **thus will give false when used in browsers not supporting HTML5.**